# How can I exclude from a certain date in my dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Given I have the following dataset:

```
     reference     country         date                   title     author  is_gov  text
0   r901128a_BOA    australia   1990-11-28 00:00:00     A Proper Role for Monetary Policy   fraser  0   They would no doubt argue that to have two obj...
1   r911003a_BOA    australia   1991-10-03 00:00:00         fraser  0   Today I wish to talk about real interest rates...
```

The problem is briefly explained, I wish to include dates that are after or on Janaury 1st 2016. To do so, I've ran the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:...",parse_dates=['date'])
df1 = df[['reference','country','date','title','author','is_gov','text']].copy()
  

start = dt.datetime(2016,1,1)
df1 = df1[df1['date']>=start]
df1
```

Upon running 6th line I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: You are comparing string variables to date variables. They are not compatible types. The read_excel statement reads your date terms from excel as a string. You can only compare a string to a string or a date to a date. change you comparison statement to df1 = df1[datetime.strptime(df1['date'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")>=start]

Comment: Did you make sure `df1['date']` is correctly converted to datetime data type?